# using flush on lodash's throttle decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Using TypeScript (JavaScript and Angular):

I want lodash's throttle decorator to limit an API call while the user is navigating around the page, but still fire before they unload (leave) the site.

In the typescript constructor I have `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => this.onUnload());`

with the `onUnload()` function being declared as

```
onUnload() {
    this.thisIsTheThrottledFunction.flush;
}
```

but I am getting the error response "Property 'flush' does not exist on type '() => Promise'."

The function whose `.flush` method I am trying to access is the declared throttled version of the other function. The function is successfully throttled, so I am confident that part of the code works. What is the best way to access the `.flush` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug this by verifying what the value of `this` is. Seems to me like you just need to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the object's `this` value to the `onUnload` function (or you can pass it in). For instance, you could put this in your constructor: `this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this)`. There's a sugar for this syntax, where you define it in your class using `onUnload = () => { ... }`. Both of those methods attach the method to the instance instead of just having it as part of the prototype. Or, you could pass the bound function directly to your event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload.bind(this));
```

Comment: The `this.onUnload.bind(this))` was a very helpful comment, but didn't solve the issue that was causing the error response. This was fixed by making the `onUnload()` method be
`(<any>this.thisIsTheThrottledFunction).flush();`
by forcing the `any` type on the `thisIsTheThrottledFunction`